# How do I partition in MIPS with recursive calling?

Tags: assembly, mips

I am tasked with sorting a line of numbers. The method I have to use is partioning a line of numbers with recursion using MIPS. I have some code that I wrote so far, and put it into basic english what I need to do, but I am struggling to understand how the entire partition operation is going to work, especially with the recursive calling. I just cannot seem to fully wrap my head around it.

```
.data
array: .word 6 8 1 7 5 2 3 4 9 3 5
length: .word 11

.text
.globl main

main:
    la $a0, array
    li $a1, 0
    lw $a2, length
    addi $a2, $a2, -1
    
    jal quickSort
    li $v0, 10 #system code for exit
    syscall #exit

quickSort:
    
    bge $a1, $a2, endIf
    move $s0, $a0 #array
    move $s1, $a1 #zero
    move $s2, $a2 #length
    jal partition
    #pull a num from the array
    #check if num < num next to it
        #if num < next swap
    #else, recursive
    
partition:
    move $t0, $s0 #start
    move $t1, $s0 #value
```

Thank you for your help!

I have tried a couple of things, I put it into basic english and just tried coding it out, but I keep running a dead halt on partitioning. I just cannot understand it.

Comment: First, start with a C or high level language version, and attempt to translate literally, which is to say, don't do any optimizations in taking it to assembly, do those optimizations in C first, then do what the C code says, and again I stress, literally.  If you have the same control flow in assembly than in C, then the assembly will run the same, barring translation bugs.  P.S. make sure the C version works before bothering to translate to assembly.   Assembly questions at this step are: how to use local variables, how to do if-then-else, etc.. basically how to do same in assembly as in C.

Comment: Second, since this involves recursion, which involves function calling, you'll have to understand register usages and stack handling for functions that call functions.  This topic has been extensively written about both here on stackoverflow and elsewhere, but can be very confusing for the beginner first starting assembly.  Assembly questions at this step are about how/why to use the stack to save/restore registers, how to pass parameters, etc..

Comment: Can you see how the kinds of assembly questions I refer to are different from how to do quicksort or its partition in assembly?  We don't have to think in assembly!  Starting with working stuff in other languages, we can simply do the same in assembly..

Comment: In case it isn't clear, recursion is no harder than function calling.  Because MIPS, like most modern architectures, offers a recursive-capable call stack, just following the calling convention for one function calling another is sufficient to handle recursion.